# Android request permission without ContextCompat

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I have an app that has the permissions in the manifest, but crashes on the second line:

```
nativeLocationManager = mainActivity.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as NativeLocationManager;
nativeLocationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(NativeLocationManager.GpsProvider, 0, 0, nativeLocationListener);
```

What am I missing?

All related answers I've checked reference ContextCompat, but I am not using ContextCompat.

Answer (score 0):

> All related answers I've checked reference ContextCompat, but I am not
>   using ContextCompat.

Any specific reason for not using ContextCompat? If that is the case, I would suggest you think again and use ContextCompat, the very first reason is that it is embedded in support library and you will not have any downside using this. Even [official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-check) recommend using ContextCompat for runtime permission.

Comment: I do not want to reference the support libraries, and I would think that I shouldn't need the support libraries to access GPS location?